# Unable to correctly calculate total area using trapezoid rule

Tags: matlab

Say we have following equations

```
dt = 0.1                       % Time interval [min]
t =  [0:dt:9]                      % Time vector [min]
v =  -300*t.^2+2700*t      % Velocity [km/min]
```

I want to solve the problem below. It seems to be asking for the trapezoid rule. The questions was posted by my professor's assistant. Note that `trapz` is not allowed and we must use three lines of code.

> (iii). Estimate the total change in position using the velocity
>   equation.
>        To do this, you can use the trapezoidal rule (look it up) with each
>        interval of length dt. (Note: You can do this in exactly one line of
>        code. If you were to take this apart and do it 90 times, that would take
>       awhile. Think about it like this: to find the area of a trapezoid, you
>        need 3 values, the two bases, and the height. We can call the height dt.
>        The two bases are values of v seperated by dt. So for the first
>        calculation, the two values would be v(1) and v(2). Use this and how to
>        calculate the area of a trapezoid and you should get a number very close to the
>        actual height of a geosynchonous satellite (pretty cool huh?)
>        (Hint: The way you can do this in one line is with row vectors, create
>        two vectors, both of length 90, each holding different values of v)
>        (Double Hint: use the sum() command in order to get a scalar value for
>        the max)

The instructions for the answer are given below

```
....         %The first 90 values of v
.....          %The last 90 values of v
.....        %Scalar value of the total distance traveled
```

My first solution is

```
v1 =  v(1:end-1)                  %The first 90 values of v
 v2 =  v(2:end)                   %The last 90 values of v
 x_total = 0.5*sum(v1+v2)*dt %Scalar value of the total distance traveled
```

The computer registered this as incorrect.

I tried the next solution

```
v1 =  v(1:end-1)                  %The first 90 values of v
 v2 =  v(2:end)                   %The last 90 values of v
 x_total = 0.5*(sum(v1*dt)+sum(v2*dt)) %Scalar value of the total distance traveled
```

The computer registered this as incorrect.

I emailed the Professor, he said x_total is wrong and there was something wrong with the sum. I did not understand how the sum was wrong so I emailed him again. He didn't reply for two days.

Why is my answer incorrect? What is the correct solution?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the area of a trapezoid?

Comment: Well, as your professor already told you, the formula for x_total is wrong.

Comment: @user125918 But I think your calculation for the area is not correct. you should scrutinize more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you calculate the trapezoidal numerical integral correctly, i.e. it returns the same result as `trapz(t, v)`.

Note that you implemented the same method as mentioned in the [`trapz`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html#bua4lsr) documentation:

> [image]

Also the implementation of `trapz` is very simular (but more general):

> ```
> z = diff(x,1,1).' * (y(1:m-1,:) + y(2:m,:))/2;
> ```

Comment: The answer "there is no problem with your code" isn't really an answer anyway... in fact it's a close-vote reason.

Comment: @Wolfie Not completely. It is validating the solution of the OP. Based on the information the OP gave to us, the professor seems to be wrong.